# Regexp на количество символов без учета пробелов

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Проверяю поле на количество введенных цифр, их должно быть 19. Все просто, но как сделать проверку на количество символов БЕЗ учета пробелов.
1234 5678 9012 1234 789
1234567890121234789

Comment: регэксп для поиска пробелов `\s`, все кроме пробелов `\S`
что то вроде такого `'1234 5678 9012 1234 789 '.match(/\S/g).length;`

Comment: Проверяете ли, что там кроме цифр и пробелов ничего нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'1234 5678 9012 1234 789 1234567890121234789'.replace(/ /g, '').length;
```

Comment: '1234 5678 9012 1234 789 1234567890121234789'.replace(/\s+/g, '').length;

Comment: @Mic, неверно же - только первое вхождение заменится.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, факт, черт возьми. Никак не привыкну к этим фичам JS.

Comment: Спасибо, коллеги, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот:​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

```
/^\s*(\d\s*){19}$/
```